# Spring boot append previously entered url in login url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a Spring boot with spring security project and need some help on below issue.

Right now, it is working like this - 
when any user tries to access `http://localhost:8080/coinMarketCap` link, he/she get redirects to `http://localhost:8080/` (which is login page) .

Now, what I am trying to implement is this -
when any user will try to access `http://localhost:8080/coinMarketCap` link, he/she will redirected to `http://localhost:8080/?target=coinMarketCap` (which is login page) .

Note that there is `?target=coinMarketCap` appended in the url

GitHub link for project : [Link](https://github.com/shivammishra217/CryptoWorld)
Configuration file : [Link](https://github.com/shivammishra217/CryptoWorld/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cryptoworld/config/SecurityConfiguration.java)

I have searched for it but couldn't find solution.
Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First suggestion is to show some of the code from your setup (in addition to your link - show what you suspect is the area that is failing).  Specific problems are usually easily found by reviewing code... second set of eyes.  Second suggestion is to take a look at extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter to make a Request Interceptor to evaluate requests and route them.

Comment: @Carter. Thanks for looking into it. Basically, I don't have any idea of how to grab previously entered url and in which method/class should I grab it, that's why I din't provide any code snippets , instead I provided link to whole project. Thanks for your second suggestion I will look into it.

Comment: @Shivam you are using antMatchers which doesn't consider the query params. So use .regexMatchers() which is also kind of  [RequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RegexRequestMatcher.html)

Comment: Spring Security supports this out-of-the-box. But what is it you want to achieve? The redirect through ap parameter or just that the user redirects to the earlier requested page?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for looking into it. I know that spring security automatically redirects to previously entered url after successful login and right now this is what is happening in my application. I don't want to redirect through parameters and I just want to redirect to earlier requested page which is spring security by default behavior . Thanks.

Comment: Your comment is confusing. You state that the default behavior works. Your Question States you want to use a parameter but in your comment you state you don’t want this??? Which is it and why. Because a URL alone might not be enough to do the redirect/original request. Especially with POST/PUT requests.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry for misunderstanding here. Basically, I want to append previously requested url to the login url.

Comment: But why? Why do you need this? What is the usecase? You have a working solution (Spring Security provides that), so what is the usecase for the additional property?

Comment: @M.Deinum It tells the user that before accessing the entered url, you need to login first.

Comment: Doesn't redirecting to the login page already does that? Also some browsers don't even show the full URL so adding the parameter doesn't make sense then. But if you really want you can create your own extension of the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` which would append the parameter. But I would say that that is a lot of work for little to no gain.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for you suggestion. I will try to implement it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add parameters to the login page the easiest way may be to add a handler with path parameters like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{name}/{age}")
public String getMessage(@PathVariable("name") String name, 
        @PathVariable("age") String age) {
    <here redirect to "/" with parameters>
}
```

With Thymeleaf it works like this:

```
return "redirect:/?name=" + name + "&age=" + age;
```

You can find many guides how to redirect with Spring. But you'll need to open access to all the pages that need such handling.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Yes, this is correct way to customize url mappings. Can you please also guide me how to get previously entered url and passing it to this customize url mapping. Thanks.